# Is there a way style a div so its children are rendered as if they were children of the div's parent node?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a document with a grandparent node A, a parent node B and two child nodes C and D.

```
    A 
  -----
 /  |  \
X   B   Y
   / \
  C   D

This is what my document structure looks like
```

A, C, D, X and Y can be any nodes. Is there a way to style node B so that the resulting document will render as if C and D were direct children of A?

```
    A 
  -----
 / | | \
X  C D  Y

Is there a way to style the original document
so it renders the same as this other document?
```

The reason I ask this is that I am working with a widget library that only allows widgets to have a single root node. I wonder: if I wanted to have a widget corresponding to the sibling nodes B and C, is there a way to pack those two nodes into a single wrapper node that happens to be "ignored" when the document is rendered?

So far the closest thing I could think of is having the widget return a documentFragment but that goes against some of the existing code that expects the wrapper node to be present in the document structure.

Comment: If the children are taken out of the document flow (using `position:absolute` or `fixed`) and the parent doesn't have a stacking order then kind of. Otherwise no, as there is no use because if you want them outside then you'll change the HTML. If it's really necessary to do so you need to use javascript to move the node

Comment: I don't understand. If you CSS rules of the form `.A .C`, they will work the same whether or not `B` is there. Document fragments won't help here because they are by definition not in the DOM. PS. In your question, did you mean to say "sibling nodes C and D"?

Comment: For example, if X, C, D, Y are display:inline then if B were display:block it would mess up the end result (I want it to look like as if B werent there). When I refer to sibling nodes its  just to emphasize that C and D are both children of the same node. Yes, I know documentFragments dont work, but I mentioned them anyway because if they didnt vanish from the DOM it would do exactly what I want.